# Placement of "off the beaten track" in context

Tags: idioms, adjectives, word-order

I know that "off the beaten track" means "unusual". Can it be used before a noun and after a verb?

For example,

> - an off the beaten track place
> - This holiday is off the beaten track.

Is it used only when talking about things?

Comment: As for the first usage, I'd hyphenate it: an _off-the-beaten-track restaurant_, e.g. After a verb is fine: _That restaurant is off the beaten track._

Comment: I think “a restaurant off the beaten track” is preferable to previous forms; as in e.g. “At a restaurant off the beaten track we ordered dinner.”

Comment: @J.R. I think this rule applies when the phrase starts to get long. Like "It was a long-haul trip" looks fine. But when you start hyphenating four or five words together, it starts to look clumsy. It all depends on context, rhythm, etc, of course.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

"*Off the beaten track*" means out of the ordinary or unusual, but that's not its only meaning. It can also mean in a remote location, or somewhere that's out of the way or out of a central, popular or touristy area.

You can use it as an attributive adjective:

> [They found a quiet **off-the-beaten-track** resort.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+beaten+track)

Like what @J.R. commented, you'll need hyphens to make an adjective out of a phrase.

You can also use it as a predicative adjective:

> [The farmhouse we stayed in was completely **off the beaten track**.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/off-the-beaten-track)

---

It's often used for things and places, but it can also be used to talk about people:

> [What do they think of you being so far **off the beaten track**?](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-the-beaten-track)
>
> [Women Writers **off the Beaten Track**](http://louisville.edu/diversity/women-writers-off-the-beaten-track-alice-notley.ics)

Comment: Nice answer, Cool Elf. Good examples.

Comment: I appreciate that coming from you, @JLG